# how to void an envelope using C# / XML?

Tags: docusignapi

Can anyone tell me how to fix this code, I just get an 400 error:

```
public string VoidEnvelope(string envelopeID)
{
    string url = baseURL + "/envelopes/" + envelopeID;
    string requestBody =
"<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
"<status>voided</status>" +
"<voidedReason>user aborted</voidedReason>" +
"</envelopeDefinition>";
    HttpWebRequest request = initializeRequest(url, "PUT", requestBody, email, password);
    string response = getResponseBody(request);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating an envelope by doing a `POST` to the `/envelopes` URI the outer most XML element is defined as

```
<envelopeDefinition ...
```

However when modifying an existing envelope using a `PUT`, the outer most XML element is defined simply as

```
<envelope ...
```

So try something like this:

```
"<envelope>" +
"<status>voided</status>" +
"<voidedReason>user aborted</voidedReason>" +
"</envelope>";
```

A great resource that many people (including myself) forget about is the Rest API help page.  That is probably your best way of learning the XML request bodies and all the potential nodes (it's also great for JSON!)

https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help

Comment: Thanks Ergin, that worked great, and the link you provided is also extremely helpful.

Comment: This was very helpful I ran into the same issue as well. Thanks!